# Как конвертировать Key-Value таблицу в Key-Values в Postgres?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Собственно, эти данные являются агрегированными характеристиками товаров по определенной товарной категории, и используются для построения фильтров для интернет каталога. После обхода всех товаров в БД, я имею таблицу с уникальными парами:

**attr**, **value**

brand, samsung

brand, huawei

brand, htc

color, white

color, black

color, red

color, pink

color, orange

color, olive

type, slim

type, ultraslim

Где **attr** и **value** это данные типа VARCHAR(40)

Используя возможности Postgres по работе с массивами, мне нужно представить эти данные в формате, удобном для восприятия интернет каталогом (данные будут рендериться в хтмл форму с селектами):

**attr**, **values**

brand, (samsung, huawei, htc)

color, (white, black, red, pink, orange, olive)

type, (slim, ultraslim)

Где **values** это массив типа VARCHAR(40)[]

Как реализовать данную конвертацию стандартными средствами Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
SELECT
    attr
    ,array_agg("value") "values"
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    attr
```

В `values` будет массив. [Вот](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html) еще описание функций агрегирования. [Тут](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html) описание функций работы с массивами

Comment: Великолепно, все работает, спасибо вам